# Passing data in a repeated directive

Tags: angularjs

I would like to access "num" in the "link" attribute. But I cannot just do `value={{num}}`. What is the proper way to do that?

### HTML

```
<div class="customDirective" ng-repeat="num in [1,2,3]"></div>
```

### Directive

```
function customDirective(loggedUserService) {
    return{
        restrict: "C",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //I would like to access num
        },
        template: "<div>some stuff</div>"
    };
}

app = angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .directive('customDirective', customDirective)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    alert(scope.num);
```

Comment: Perfect! It was easier than I thought. Thank you very much

Comment: Strangely enough `class="customDirective"` and `class="custom-directive"` both work :-o

Comment: Because it's actually a css class, it would't work if it was an element (restrict: "E") I suppose.

Comment: The documentation says: `The directive can be invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case` :D

Comment: Yep! Fails when you invoke it as an attr or an element. I dont think the documentation mentions it anywhere.